# Enabling and disabling network connection in android

Tags: android, networking, connectivity

in my application i can enable and disable wifi connection.After disabling wifi connection it switches to mobile network for accessing internet.I want to disable mobile connection also and then enable it after a certain period.I am enabling and disabling wifi using WifiManager. But what to do enable/disable 2g/3g mobile network.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way (and only one?) is to rename the APN and then rename it back. Is beeing used by many apps

Comment: how to rename APN.Please give some details.

Comment: Check this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833198/enable-mobile-network)